# Symfony Doctrine reset database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to connect my symfony database with Sequel Pro (Database manegement tool) but the way Symfony set up doctrine when I first installed it was with "sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db" and I cannot change this to mysql and set a custom password and user.

Is there any way to reset doctrine so I can start from scratch and set up the database with my own password and user?

I have tried doctrine:database:dump but this has not helped nor has it helped to remove doctrine and install it again.

Comment: I have also tried "$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getConnection()->getPassword()" to see if I could get the password but this returns null.

Comment: What version of Symfony are you using? You don't need to remove and reinstall Doctrine, you just need to configure it properly in `config.yml` to set the driver and `parameters.yml` to set host, port, db name, user and password (assuming you're on a 2.8 version).

Comment: I am not sure how to do that?

Comment: Again what version of Symfony are you using?

Comment: I'm using the newest version of Symfony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you're using Symfony 4 you need to update your `.env` file in order to use MySQL. Search for:

```
DATABASE_URL="sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/app.db"
```

and replace it with:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name"
```

of course you need to customise it with user/password and database name you want to use.

Then in `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` make sure to have something like:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

here make sure to set the right MySQL server version you're using.